# Is there any android app or software that allow me to create my own chess puzzle so I can solve or study it later on?

Tags: software, puzzles, android

I want to improve my tactics skills; is there any Android app or software that allows me to create my own chess puzzle so I can solve or study it later on?

Answer (score 2):

LiChess or Chess.com have apps accessible to Android, in which you can find an analysis board and study from there. You can save the boards as well until further use.

Plus, there are a lot of features, such as finishing game with computer, analysis from engine etc.

Comment: Thanks, any app i can use offline?

Comment: The app works offline for both of them. However, you can't play any live chess.

Comment: I also can not open chess puzzle too

Comment: I believe puzzles should work. If this answer helped you, could you approve it?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend my own chess puzzle editor https://www.apronus.com/chess/puzzle/editor.php

On this long page with many links https://www.apronus.com/chess/puzzles/ you can get an idea for what kind of puzzles my editor can create.

Comment: Thanks, this is free right? I'll try it later

Comment: It is free for personal use. You can create puzzles and save them as links.